# Which tests can be used for variables that are non-normal, but have homogenous variances?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, ecology

I am trying to compare the effect of two treatments (planting distance) on the growth of plants (multiple species), using the variable growth rate in diameter for multiple years. 
I have 4 sets of values for the growth rate (growth rate for each treatment and data for 2 years), but with different sample sizes (by including every plant). I understand that the sample sizes can be the same if I choose plants randomly. 
However, on checking for normality and homogeneity of variances, I found that one set of values are non-normal but have homogenous variances, whereas the others are non-normal and have heterogeneous variances. 
Which test would be the most suitable for such data values?

Comment: I think there is no general answer without understanding your data more. Providing a histogram for each set of values would be a good start, some more mathematical theory of plant growth would also be great (if available). Note that it is not surprising that growth rates are non-normal as (I assume) negative growth rates do not occur while normal distribution would assume they are OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to test for statistical significant difference between the two treatments you could use bootstrapping to do random sample-tests.

I also highly suggest reading this article by Allen Downey on the subject of statistical testing: [There is still only one test](http://allendowney.blogspot.com/2016/06/there-is-still-only-one-test.html) as well as Jake Vanderplas' presentation at PyCon2016 on the same subject: [Statistics for Hackers - PyCon 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7I7MWTX0gA)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a mixed model approach since it seems you have repeated measures (actually I do not understand your experiment design), if you don't have repeat measures you can use a linear model with treatments as explanatory variables. In the modelling approach you must concern only with residuals normality and variance homogeneity, even if your response are not normally distributed.